# Как сделать путь в хлебных крошках как мне нужно в битрикс 1с

Tags: битрикс

Не получается сделать хлебные крошки с помощью компонента битрикс. Когда я хочу сделать по такому пути

```
 Главная -> Название элемента
```

а выходит у меня в следующем виде:

```
Главная->t-sitrak-4x2-c7h-max-akpp-retarder->Преимущества
```

Я не пойму откуда у меня берется Преимущества. В свойствах раздела я прописал t-sitrak-4x2-c7h-max-akpp-retarder.
Компонент "хлебные крошки" битрикс:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:breadcrumb", 
    "template2", 
    array(
        "START_FROM" => "0",
        "PATH" => "",
        "SITE_ID" => "s1",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "template2"
    ),
    false
);?>
```

Тут можно посмотреть: https://aaa-sitrak.ru/t-sitrak-4x2-c7h-max-akpp-retarder/

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Решил сам эту проблему. У меня на странице был еще один инфоблок-"Преимущества" - просто забыл про него. Сделал, чтобы он не участвовал в цепочки навигации в се норм)